# How to install AMD Catalyst 15.3 (fglrx 15.20.1013) on Fedora 22?

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, amd-graphics, dkms

I to install the AMD Catalyst 15.3 driver in Fedora 22, since that is the only driver that supports the X11 server 1.17.

Answer (score 3):

*****UPDATE*****

AMD released a new version of Catalyst, therefore, no longer need to use my driver, here are the [link](https://bluehatrecord.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/installing-the-proprietary-amd-catalyst-15-7-fglrx-15-20-driver-on-fedora-22-with-linux-kernel-4-0-6/) which is a guide to install Catalyst 15.7 on Fedora 22.

I'll leave my answer about installing Catalyst if any of you still want to use my driver.

I hope my driver were to have served during this time, I will continue making contributions to GNU/Linux.

---

---

---

I have some time trying to install Catalyst 15.3 on Fedora 22. Since the driver is only available in Ubuntu, I decided to try making my own driver (I did not programmed) and after several attempts I made it, I built one driver, who you can install generically on any GNU/Linux distribution.

The following instructions are for installing the driver on Fedora 21/22:

1. Update all your system correctly:

   > sudo dnf upgrade

and then restart your system.

2. Download the driver that I did it from here:

   > [R4v3nPr0_AMD_Catalyst_15.3](https://mega.co.nz/#!q09CzB7L!iCrIJqhWD5De-P_n-D6vPc3XCLsreEBo1avtyC99IeE)
3. Uncompress the driver.
4. After having uncompressed, open a terminal in the folder you extracted and run the following commands:

   > sudo dnf install gcc gcc-c++ make kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms fakeroot
   >
   > sudo cp /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include/linux/
   >
   > sudo ./ati-installer.sh 15.20 --install
   >
   > sudo aticonfig --initial
5. (Recommended) If you are using GNOME:

If you use GNOME + gdm, you will experience some problems with the driver, to correct these problems follow these instructions (this works in Fedora 21/22, I do not know if it works in other distributions):

- Download the following script:

  > [catalyst-fix-gdm.sh](https://mega.co.nz/#!Lk8nkahL!aWCACqHMwsY9Lix5LLy2bdqxK-qnpp8rzZjIErVq_L4)
- Then run the following commands in the folder where you downloaded
  the script:

  > su
  >
  > dnf install lightdm
  >
  > systemctl disable gdm
  >
  > systemctl enable lightdm
  >
  > sh catalyst-fix-gdm.sh

6.  After you have correctly followed the guide, reboot your system and enjoy the driver