# How to install AMD Catalyst on Fedora 22 with GNOME?

Tags: gnome, fglrx, amd-graphics, dkms, mutter

today I installed AMD Catalyst on Fedora 22. After rebooting my computer, my screen was black.

I have read several guidebooks, but I have not found a way to run "Catalyst" on GNOME on laptops.

If someone has managed to run GNOME on Fedora 22 and has a laptop, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found the way to run fglrx on Fedora 22 GNOME laptops. I relied on guides I had done, but I had not succeeded before, in a formal way which today I bring to you.

I want to clarify that this guide is intended for users of Fedora 22 GNOME that use laptops.

If you want to know how to install fglrx on Fedora 22, you can follow these guidelines:

- [How to install AMD Catalyst 15.3 (fglrx 15.20.1013) on Fedora
  22?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211165/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-15-3-fglrx-15-20-1013-on-fedora-22)
- [Installing the Proprietary AMD Catalyst 15.9 (fglrx 15.201) driver
  on Fedora 22 with Linux Kernel 4.1.6](https://bluehatrecord.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/installing-the-proprietary-amd-catalyst-15-9-fglrx-15-201-driver-on-fedora-22-with-linux-kernel-4-1-6/)

Then I place a link to a folder of MEGA that contains several mutter packages (You can ignore the package mutter-devel-3.16.4-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm):

- [mutter packages](https://mega.nz/#F!i0sUkIqC!AcikRhejciF-XaQBVzvS0A)

**Note: I clarify that for the moment I've only packaging mutter for amd64 architecture.**

All you have to do is download and install the packages:

```
sudo dnf install *.rpm
```

**Extra:**

In the first guide presented above, it says it is necessary to install LightDM, you can skip this step and download the two scripts that are in the folder of MEGA, and run with superuser privileges.

```
su
sh catalyst-fix-gdm.sh
sh catalyst-fix-gnome-session.sh
```

**Warning:**

It is important to disable SELinux for all the above take effect. For this I leave this link:

- [How to Disable SELinux](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html)